# Axios Encrypted POST parameters

Tags: rest, post, header, axios, signing

I want to use the API from bitgrail (docs: https://bitgrail.com/api-documentation). And request the amount of balances. To do that you have to set a SIGNATURE which includes the encrypted post parameters using HMAC-SHA512 with ur API-Secret.

So you have to sent this data:

Header:

> KEY - Public API key
>
> SIGNATURE - encrypted POST parameters with HMAC-SHA512 alghoritm using your secret API key

Data:

> nonce - Integer number, always greater then nonce of previous call.

But everytime I try to send the request I get an 'Authentication failed'-Error from Bitgrail.

The params are set like so:

```
params = {}
params.nonce = n();
```

and then encrypted like this:

```
 let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', 'MYSECRET');
 let digest = hmac.update(params.toString()).digest('hex');
 let signature = new Buffer(digest).toString('base64');
```

Maybe the 'params.toString()' is not working. Do I have to set the params variable as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it our by myself by using const `{ URLSearchParams } = require('url');`
and deleting this line: `let signature = new Buffer(digest).toString('base64');` and just using the digest as signature.